# Spark - operate a non serialized method on every element in a JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Is it possible to go over elements in the JavaPairRDD but to perform some calculation `f()` on one machine only?

Each element `(x,y)` in the JavaPairRDD is a record (features and label), and I would like to call some calculation `f(x,y)` which can't be serialized. 
`f()` is an self-implemented algorithm that updates some weights $w_i$. 
The weights $w_i$ should be the same object for data from all partitions (rater broke up into tasks - each of which is operated on by an executor).

**Update:**
What I'm trying to do is to run "algo" `f()` 100 times in such a way that every iteration of algo is single-threaded but the whole 100 iterations run in parallel on different nodes. In high level, the code is something like that:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> dataPairs = ... // Load the data
boolean withReplacement = true; 
double testFraction =  0.2;
long seed = 0;
Map classFractions = new HashMap(); 
classFractions.put("1", 1 - testFraction);
classFractions.put("0", 1 - testFraction);

dataPairs.cache();

for (1:100) 
{
    PredictionAlgorithm algo = new Algo();

    JavaPairRDD<String, String> trainStratifiedData = dataPairs.sampleByKeyExact(withReplacement, classFractions, seed);
    algo.fit(trainStratifiedData);

}
```

I would like that `algo.fit()` will update the same weights $w_i$ instead of fitting weights for every partition.

Comment: if you can calculate these weights for each partition alone and combine them _afterwards_, then [RDD.mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#mapPartitions(scala.Function1,%20boolean,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) might be useful - you'd pass a function that maps each partition to an iterator with one item (the resulting algo object), the returned RDD will have 100 records which you can `collect()` and combine in driver code.

Comment: @TzachZohar I know, but I raised this question because I wanted to avoid implementing parallel training of my algo (since this is not an easy task at all). I wanted to enjoy the privilege of processing my dataset with Spark but didn't know that this is (as at seems) impossible to operate one threaded algorithm on data from all partitions.